# How to get a Bitmap from a drawable defined in a xml?

Tags: android

How can I get the bitmap from a xml shape drawable. 
What am I doing wrong?

**shadow.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270.0"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="#33000000"
        android:type="linear" />

    <size android:height="7.0dip" />

</shape>
```

My method to retrieve the bitmap from drawable:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int id) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), id);
}
```

getBitmap() is returning null when the id passed in is the **shadow.xml** drawable id.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

a ShapeDrawable doesn't have a bitmap associated with it - its sole purpose is to be drawn on a canvas.  Until its draw method is called, it has no image.  If you can get a canvas element at the place where you need to draw the shadow, you can draw it as a shapeDrawable, otherwise you might need a separate, empty view in your layout with the shadow as a background.

Comment: thank you for the good explanation. I drawn it directly on canvas and worked fine.

Comment: @kaneda can you show the code that finally worked? I'm facing the same issue here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That would be something along the lines of

    `Drawable d = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.id);`
    `d.draw(canvas);`

Comment: @JFreebird I'm sorry. I don't have the code anymore, so the best I could do now is give it a guess.
IMO the best would be if you could post a question describing your problem so others can see. And if you feel like doing it, link your question here in the comments so I can give it a look. Maybe I can have an insight :)

Answer (score 78):

This is a fully **working solution**:

```
private Bitmap getBitmap(int drawableRes) {
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(drawableRes);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

And here is an example:

```
Bitmap drawableBitmap = getBitmap(R.drawable.circle_shape);
```

**circle_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#94f5b6" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#487b5a"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: It throws  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: Just a minor compatibility update : change "getResources().getDrawable(drawableRes);" by "ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes);"

Comment: In case you want to use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableRes);` as suggested by @Tobliug you will have to add the `support-v4 library` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#v4.

Comment: @BMU you need to define the size in the shape drawable if you wish to use it like this. By default the shape drawable doesn't have a size defined. So add something like

    <size android:height="68dp" android:width="375dp" />


and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

You should add size attribute to your shape drawable for preventing  "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0".

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
       <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
       <stroke
           android:width="1.3dp"
           android:color="@color/white" />

       <size android:height="24dp" android:width="24dp"/>
</shape>
```