# Android - SVG file import

Tags: android, svg, background-image

I want to use svg drawable with Android Studio. I use drawable->New->Vector Asset->Local File, but it doesn't import my svg file. I try this file with [svg2android](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) it throws some warnings.

> Warning #1:   stroke-width not found on path one or more times. Defaulting all instances to 1.
> Warning #2: transforms on path are not supported, use option Bake transforms into path

Generated xml file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="100dp"
android:height="100dp"
android:viewportWidth="100"
android:viewportHeight="100">

<path
    android:strokeColor="#66899a"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 0 -44 C 3.31370849898 -44 6 -24.3005289926 6 0 C 6 24.3005289926 3.31370849898 44 0 44 C -3.31370849898 44 -6 24.3005289926 -6 0 C -6 -24.3005289926 -3.31370849898 -44 0 -44 Z" />
<path
    android:strokeColor="#e1d85d"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 0 -44 C 3.31370849898 -44 6 -24.3005289926 6 0 C 6 24.3005289926 3.31370849898 44 0 44 C -3.31370849898 44 -6 24.3005289926 -6 0 C -6 -24.3005289926 -3.31370849898 -44 0 -44 Z" />
<path
    android:strokeColor="#80a3cf"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 0 -44 C 3.31370849898 -44 6 -24.3005289926 6 0 C 6 24.3005289926 3.31370849898 44 0 44 C -3.31370849898 44 -6 24.3005289926 -6 0 C -6 -24.3005289926 -3.31370849898 -44 0 -44 Z" />
<path
    android:strokeColor="#4b541f"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M 0 -44 C 24.3005289926 -44 44 -24.3005289926 44 0 C 44 24.3005289926 24.3005289926 44 0 44 C -24.3005289926 44 -44 24.3005289926 -44 0 C -44 -24.3005289926 -24.3005289926 -44 0 -44 Z" />
```

Does android support fully svg? If yes, how can I import this file? Also, I want to set background drawable programmatically. Is it possible without using R.drawable.svgXml? Can I generate bitmap from xml?

Comment: Does android support fully svg? No, it has some limitations, it doesn't support some SVG properties, like the ones you're experiencing. Try looking for other online tools that convert it to android-compatible.

Comment: what warning ?? can you send it?

Answer (score 0):

> Does android support fully svg?

Obviously not, otherwise it would not show you those warnings that state "X not supported".

You have to change the SVG if you want to use it.

> Can I generate bitmap from xml?

See here [How to get a Bitmap from a drawable defined in a xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111073/how-to-get-a-bitmap-from-a-drawable-defined-in-a-xml)

Comment: Can I generate bitmap from xml? I wonder that can I parse xml file(not under drawable folder) as png or anything? I know that I can create bitmap from resource id.

Comment: what do you mean "from xml"?

Comment: I want to load svg image dynamically. I convert svg to xml. Then I put this xml file under device sdcard. In this case, vector drawable file is not under drawable folder. So, I cannot get using R.darawable.xxx. How can I load this xml file as bitmap/drawable?